# Error in run time Permission in Android

Tags: android, permissions, kotlin

Hiii, when i create the run time Permission in my app the error is gone, here no problem, but when i make  override on the (onRequestPermissionsResult) method, and make sure to give the Premission by user, also show me Error about Permission? why that? and how can i overcome it?: this error is:

```
Call required permission which maybe rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available...etc)
```

this is my code:

```
private fun startLocationUpdates() {
if( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@DisplayMembers, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION), REQUEST_DISP_LOC)
}else {
    //=====================//
    mFusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest(),
            LocationCallBack(),
            null)
    //====================//
}
```

}

and:

```
 override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    when(requestCode){
        REQUEST_DISP_LOC -> {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                mFusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest(),
                        LocationCallBack(),
                        null)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the complete error message

Comment: it is the Design time error, the same error when i don't check the permission? it is:

 (Call required permission which maybe rejected by user: code should explicitly  check to see if permission is available...etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used to call `mFusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates` inside `onRequestPermissionResult`. There are only granted results array, not permission details. So you only know which permission called first and which permissions are granted but the android studio doesn't know it.

So you have to call like this:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    when(requestCode){
        REQUEST_DISP_LOC -> {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               startLocationUpdates()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but in this case, the process will iterate? right? because android will chick permission more thane one time?

Comment: Its just checking permission granted or not just like you did in onRequestPermissionResult

Comment: there is no way or Design Pattern to chick Permission just one time?

Comment: any doc you mean?

Comment: Yes, please go through android runtime permission.

Answer (score 1):

Because at any time, user can reject the permission, every time you are looking for user's location, you have to check do a check for permission:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
```

and then you can check the location as you wish:

```
mFusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest(),
                    LocationCallBack(),
                    null)
```

hope this helps

Comment: there is no way or Design Pattern to chick Permission just one time?

Comment: You can always user @SuppressLint to silence the IDE, but I don't suggest this. I can't think of any other way to handle this.

Comment: Thank you very much